# Jquery show hover effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="hot_post">
<header>
<ul>
    <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hot_post.png" alt="hot post"></li>
    <li><h1>Hot Post</h1></li>
</ul> 
</header>
<div class="hot_post_list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="hot_post_single">
                <a href="" class="hot_post_thumbnail"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/83/83" alt="post title"></a>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40" alt="autor_avatar" class="hot_post_avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="hot_post_title">This is post for wordrpess</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="hot_post_single">
                <a href="" class="hot_post_thumbnail"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/83/83" alt="post title"></a>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40" alt="autor_avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="hot_post_title">This is post for wordrpess</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="hot_post_single">
                <a href="" class="hot_post_thumbnail"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/83/83" alt="post title"></a>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40" alt="autor_avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="hot_post_title">This is post for wordrpess</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I like to show "hot_post_single> img " and "hot_post_title" by hovering "hot_post_thumbnail", by default they are display:hidden;

What code I should use to do this ? I like to show Only one "hot_post_single> img " and "hot_post_thumbnail" these are relative of "hot_post_thumbnail".

Comment: It's time to try to resolve your issue yourself... How this is different than your previous question?

Comment: Have you made any attempts yourself so far? You usually get a much better response posting here when you've attempted to do this yourself and then got stuck, rather than simply asking us to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it: 
$(".hot_post_thumbnail").hover(function(){

$(this).closest(".hot_post_title").show();
$(this).closest("img").show();

});